# catkin_make --install headers search order

Tags: ros, catkin-make, headers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Let's say I have 2 **packages A & B** of which **package B** use some of the **package A** headers.

I use `catkin_make_isolated --install`  to build my packages. **Package A** is builded first, then its headers is installed to **install_isolated** directory using:

`install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME} 
DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)`

The headers is then visible for **package B** to use and the compilation runs just fine.

The problem is that each time I modified headers file of **package A**, its source file looks for the headers file in **install_isolated** directory but not the ones in **include/{package A}** of source directory. The only solution I have in mind is delete the **install_isolated/{package A}/include** directory and recompile, but it is very inconvenient, not portable and not standalone runnable.

Is there a way to force source files to look for headers in its source location but not in install space, but using always  `catkin_make_isolated --install`  ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207079/catkin_make---install-headers-search-order/) by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume after building the first time you have sourced the setup file in the same shell and later try to build a second time from within the same shell?

Please try to use a separate shell for sourcing the setup. Then rebuilding the workspace in the first shell (which has not sourced the setup of that workspace) should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0